# VBA excel IsError function for special case

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a function similar to the IsError function which returns `TRUE` if the input is fishy and `FALSE` otherwise:

I have two ranges `rng1`, `rng2` and I want to perform this operation

```
IsError( rng1.value / rng2.value)
```

The function should return `TRUE` if `rng1.value` or `rng2.value` one range contains a string, is empty or `rng2.value=0`

Is there a similar function or some nice way to state these conditions? or should I just do an If-statement with all of the conditions as `or`?

Comment: You'l either have to check both the inputs before doing the calculation, or use error handling to trap and deal with the error.

Comment: Looks like a good case for a UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (Not tested, but it should do the trick):

```
  Function CheckError(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Boolean

     On Error GoTo FoundError
     Dim x As Integer

     x = rng1.Value / rng2.Value

     CheckError = False
     Exit Function

  FoundError:
     CheckError = True

  End Function
```

Comment: I think you have your `True` and `False` in the wrong place. Function should return `True` at the `FoudnError:`, right?